# Gradle + war = Wrong war content

Tags: java, gradle, war

I am using Gradle, but the output war file (on  /build/libs/project-version.war) has only the WebContent information.

Here's how I´ve set up my build.gradle file:

```
//others
apply plugin: "war"


//repos and dependencies

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run **gradle build** command the WAR content is:

[image]

Can you guys help me out setting up the correct WAR ?
Thanks

Comment: You'd have to explain in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: Ok... The problem is, that the way it is... gradle builds my WAR without classes and libs. Only with the WebContent files. (I even put an image of the war files). I need to make the WAR correct .

Comment: If the war's `lib` directory is empty or does not exist, chances are that something is wrong with your dependency declarations. If the war's `classes` directory is empty or does not exist, chances are that  the sources aren't located in the `src` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the WAR Content is correct.

If you are going to build a WAR you need to specify this for it to build correctly:

```
webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You only have to specify this if your web content and sources aren't located in the default locations. As you already had this code in your original question, I wonder how it could solve your problem.